# How to prepend only once in jQuery in a Wordpress environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am working in a Wordpress Environment. I inserted a custom section by using jquery to show a "Treasure Trove" icon so people can click on it. This icon is prepended to the default "Red Chat Icon" that is created through a chat plugin.

This makes the DIV i created directly related to the "Red Chat Icon". However whenever I open and close the default chat icon the treasure trove icon duplicates every time. How would I go about making the "Treasure Trove" icon to not duplicate every time it is opened and closed?

[image: example]

**jQuery**

```
    jQuery(document).on("wplc_animation_done", function(e) {

                    jQuery( "#wp-live-chat-header" ).append( "<div class='wp-live-chat-extend'><h2>Chat with Us!</h2></div>" ); 

            jQuery( "#wp-live-chat" ).prepend( "<a href='/exatactical/treasure-trove/'><div id='pbf-treasure-trove' class='pbf-treasure-trove-bg'></div></a>" ); // This is what inserts the icon
            jQuery( "#pbf-treasure-trove" ).append( "<div class='wp-live-chat-extend'><h2>Treasure Trove</h2></div>" );
});
```

**CSS**

```
.wp-live-chat-extend {
   opacity: 0;
   width: 72px;
   height: 72px;
}

.wp-live-chat-extend:hover{
   padding-left: 90px;
   opacity: 1;
}

.wp-live-chat-extend h2 {
   color: #fff!important;
   font-size: 20px;
   width: 200px;
   margin-top: 20px;
}

#pbf-treasure-trove {
   margin-bottom: 15px;
   background-image: url(/exatactical/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/iconRetina.png);
   background-size: cover;
}

#pbf-treasure-trove:hover {
   background-image: url(/exatactical/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/iconRetina2.png);
   background-size: cover;
}

.pbf-treasure-trove-bg {
   border-radius: 62px 62px;
   background: #00ADEF;
   width: 62px;
   height: 62px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to exploit jQuery's `.one()` method.

```
jQuery(document).on("wplc_animation_done", function(e) {
    jQuery( "#wp-live-chat-header" ).append( "<div class='wp-live-chat-extend'><h2>Chat with Us!</h2></div>" ); 
    jQuery( "#pbf-treasure-trove" ).append( "<div class='wp-live-chat-extend'><h2>Treasure Trove</h2></div>" );
}).one("wplc_animation_done", function(e) {
    jQuery( "#wp-live-chat" ).prepend( "<a href='/exatactical/treasure-trove/'><div id='pbf-treasure-trove' class='pbf-treasure-trove-bg'></div></a>" ); // This is what inserts the icon
});
```

If necessary, the other two lines can also be shuffled into the `.one()` handler.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).one()
```

`one()` only executes the handler once, vs `on()` which is persistent.

http://api.jquery.com/one/